# Pass text to menu label in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to make the text under the selection, in variable 'a' to appear as a label of the menu.
Here is the code:

```
def popup(event):
    a=t_start.get("sel.first", "sel.last")
    menu.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)
    return a

def insert_word():
    pass

t_start.bind("<Button-3>", popup)


menu = Menu(root, tearoff=0)
menu.add_command(label="Set selection 1", command=set_selection_1)
menu.add_command(label="Set selection 2", command=set_selection_2)
menu.add_command(label="%s" %popup, command=set_selection_2)
```

Right now, all I get is function popup address. 
If I try popup.a, I get an error, function has no attribute 'a'. How do I overcome this and get whatever is in 'a' to be printed as menu label?

Comment: AFAIK, callback methods are not supposed to return anything. Try adding `a` to the menu inside the `popup` method, i.e. move `menu.add_command(label=a, command=...)` there.

Comment: @tobias_k - it worked, thanks a lot. I've tried this before, but apparently there was a typo or something.

Comment: Glad I could help. I've added this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Callback methods like `popup` are not supposed to return anything. Instead, you should manipulate the `menu` from *inside* the function.

Also, as suggested by Brian, you probably rather want to modify an existing entry in the menu, instead of adding a new one each time you click the button. In this case, create the entry outside the function (like you do now), but use some placeholder for the label.

```
def popup(event):
    a = t_start.get("sel.first", "sel.last")
    menu.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)
    menu.add_command(label=a, command=set_selection_2) # add to menu
    # menu.entryconfig(2, label=a) # modify existing entry
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the text on a menu, you must use the `entryconfig` method. For example, to change the text of the first item you would do:

```
menu.entryconfig(0, label=a)
```